# Lua: Desired Results are Received Then Not Without Changing Code

Tags: lua

Right now I'm trying to use Lua to receive variables from barcodes sent out from an outside source.  When I run this, there is a variable `rotation` from the `local function rot(input)` that appears to be "buggy".  If I run this code exactly as it is with the `print` statements below, the `rotation` will appear and disappear.  Please help me understand why this may happen?

Please note:  There are two aspects of this code that I'm currently working on.  A) Code128 is not properly retrieving the variables.  B)My code can definitely be shortened.  But I'm new and learning as I go.  The main purpose for this thread is to help me understand why code will sometimes display the desired result, then won't the next minute?

Thank you.

Edited:  I've updated the code a bit to make it cleaner.  Condensed all of my `string.match` statements into tables with other barcode related fields.  Still learning and looking to make it even more cleaner.  I love learning this, but am still having the same problem with my `local function rot(input)` and getting intermittent results.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
local function rot(input)
rotTable = {["R"] = "cw", ["I"] = "180", ["B"] = "ccw"}
for k,v in pairs (rotTable) do
    if input == k then
        rotation = v
    else
        rotation = ""
    end
end
return rotation
end

local function barCode(input)

local bcID = string.match(input,"%^(B%w)")
    if bcID == "BY" then
        bcID = string.match(input,"%^BY.*%^(B%w)")
    end
local bcTable = {
    ["BC"] = {"code128", 10,  string.match(input,"%^BY.*%^BC(%u),(%d*),(%u),%u,%u%^FD(.*)%^FS")},
    ["B2"] = {"bc2of5i", 20, string.match(input,"%^B2(%u),(%d*),(%u),%u,%u%^FD(.*)%^FS")},
    ["BE"] = {"ean13", 10, string.match(input,"%^BE(%u),(%d*),(%u),%u%^FD(.*)%^FS")},
    ["B8"] = {"ean8", 10, string.match(input,"%^B8(%u),(%d*),(%u),%u%^FD(.*)%^FS")},
    ["B3"] = {"code39", 10, string.match(input,"%^B3(%u),%u,(%d*),(%u),%u%^FD(.*)%^FS")},
    ["BU"] = {"upc_a", -1, string.match(input,"%^BU(%u),(%d*),(%u),%u%,%u^FD(.*)%^FS")}
    }

for k,v in pairs (bcTable) do
    if bcID == k then
        bcFields = v
        bcType, qzone, bcR, bcH, bcHr, bcData = unpack(bcFields)
    end
end

hPos = 0
vPos = 0

bcOutput = '<'..bcType..' qzone=\"'..qzone..'\" hbb=\"0\" vbb=\"0\" bbwidth=\"1\" hpos=\"'..hPos..'\" vpos=\"'..vPos..'\" rotation = \"'..rot(bcR)..'\" bgcolor=\"0\" barcolor=\"255\" textcolor=\"255\" barwidth=\"1\" height=\"8\">'..bcData..'</'..bcType..'>'

return bcOutput

end

print(barCode("^BY3^BCN,102,N,N^FDCHF05000042^FS"))
print(barCode("^B2B,110,N,N,N^FD45681382^FS"))
print(barCode("^BUN,183,N,N,N^FD61414199999^FS"))
print(barCode("^B8I,146,N,N^FD212345645121^FS"))
print(barCode("^BEB,183,N,N^FD211234567891^FS"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what is wrong with your code, if anything, but `rot` can be written more simply as

```
local rotTable = {["R"] = "cw", ["I"] = "180", ["B"] = "ccw"}
local function rot(input)
   return rotTable[input] or ""
end
```

In general, you shouldn't need to search Lua tables. For instance, the loop `for k,v in pairs (bcTable) do` can be replace by indexing as in the code above.

Comment: Thank you for your help!  I never thought about doing it that way!  That is a great help, thank you!  Were you not receiving the `rotation` at times and not other times?